# Best place to register events in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am into an ASP.Net project now (of course, it's my first project ASP.Net :) ). We are using Dependency Injection and the solution is designed to use MVC pattern. Here is the question now.

I could see the events for different ASP.Net intrinsic controls which is used as part of custom controls is being registered in OnInit event method of the Custom control instead registering them in constructor of the custom control. Is this a good practice?? I wonder..

Thanks in advance
123Developer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the oninit is usually the place to hook events. This can vary a bit with specific scenarios though, as in some cases you might have controls inside lists that have been bound, in which case you usually don't have the hierarchy of controls so early in the asp.net lifecycle.

I suggest you try to play nice with asp.net life-cycle and events. Not doing so usually gets you into unexpected behaviors. Please check this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC then stay away from the event-driven model of the underlying ASP.NET model.

You should be handling all your controller-centric logic in your controller methods, not in any control events.

Also, I'm not 100% sure but the MVC framework doesn't support many of the standard asp.net controls (this may have changed some with the recent release candidates).  You might find that standard asp.net controls don't behave correctly.